# Get the name of the view from inside the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult LogIn(string username)
    {
        if (username == null)
            return View("404");

        return View();
    }
```

Inside the view a want to get the view **file** name. In this case the action value is always `LogIn`. But the actual view is or `LogIn` of `404`. I have a master page that need to know the exactly view name.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using the default WebFormViewEngine, you can use the next statement to receive  the view path (including its name of course):

```
<%=(ViewContext.View as WebFormView).ViewPath %>
```

Comment: WoW! what a great solution! :)

Comment: +1 Nice answer!  Thanks for showing me something new today.  @stacker Sorry I wasn't more helpful.